# Invalid key hash when using Facebook OAuth on Android

Tags: android, openssl, facebook-oauth

I have followed these steps. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/?locale=en, but get an error when trying to log in "Invalid key hash. The key hash [MY KEY HASH] does not match any stored key hashes", which is true. The stated key hash on my phone is not the same that is generated on my laptop and entered in fb developer console.

I sucessfuly run and generate a key hash.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\hjalm\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Progg\Sportsbud\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Progg\Sportsbud\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" base64
```

which i post in facebook console App settings/Basic under "Key hashes".

Why is this?

I am running app on my actual android phone with flutter.

I tried updating facebook SDK dependency in build.gradle, as well as re-generating the key hash.